# excavator badge: one-time only, or multiple times?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, edit-badges

The description of the new Excavator Badge says:

> Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months.

This looks like a one-time only badge ... still, on TeX Stack Exchange I [just got this badge three times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/104/excavator?userid=3335).

[image: screenshot]

[Others got it multiple times, too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/104/excavator).

This [did not happen on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator?userid=600500) - it seems that the job which assigned them got something wrong on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [I've got it thrice, for the same post.](http://english.stackexchange.com/badges/102/excavator?userid=8183)

Comment: I've got it twice on Gaming and DIY. Was about to post a question.

Comment: It ought to be awardable once... given that it is a "multi-level" badge with Archaeologist badge coming up next.  So it must be a bug.

Comment: This ought to teach em to introduce new badges!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was supposed to be a single grant badge...I found/fixed the issue and removed the duplicate grants, they should behave from now on.

Comment: At tex.sx, my [user profile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) now shows the correct number of badges (133, including one "Excavator" badge). The badge count at the top of the page, however, still shows  the wrong number (3 gold, 34 silver, 99 bronze badges -- the correct number of bronze badges is 96).

Comment: @lockstep - that won't correct itself until you earn a new badge.

Comment: @lockstep - This should now be corrected, we have a job that syncs these counts nightly just in case anything like this happens, and it has now completed for all sites.

Answer (score 10):

I'll add that the archeologist badge is also doing weird things:

> [image: bug]

Comment: Hmm, she gets paid to do that job.