# Where did my Excavator badge go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, edit-badges

Couple of hours ago, I was awarded the Excavator badge on Meta:

[image: Excavator]

Now, looking at my profile, the badge is no longer there. Heck, even the badges page says no one has been awarded. Was it revoked?

[image: badges]

Comment: 150 people have earned it now...

Comment: Nick works real fast ;) @CodyGray

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was [a bug in the awarding of these badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102407/excavator-badge-one-time-only-or-multiple-times/102418#102418), as part of fixing that we nuked the badges (since they were brand new anyway)...they'll be re-granted as the badge runs on each site (this may take a while).

Comment: I receive that Excavator badge without deserving it! and pointing to a post I didn't edit

Comment: @HernánEche Link to the post?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code

Comment: @Hernan: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/199418/3 You mean that the badge shouldn't be awarded for tag edits only?

Comment: @HernánEche http://i.imgur.com/FM9nq.png

Comment: Weird, I don't remember to do any edit!.. it seems like pressing "edit"->"save" with no edition.. it was a long time ago, then I think "Excavator" wouldn't correspond anyway