# "You earned x-badge and 2 other badges. See your profile"

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did my Excavator badge go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102425/where-did-my-excavator-badge-go)

I got this nice info: "You earned x-badge and 2 other badges. See your profile".

[image: info about badges] 
Well that's a nice thing, we all like <strike>bit</strike> badges. Let's have a look at them:

[image: list of badges]

Mother! Can you see it?

I don't have the smallest idea which other badge I should have earned, and there is no other badge.

Is it a bug, or don't I understand the question?

Comment: @Nick: How's that a dupe? The problem is more the "2 other badges" part.

Comment: @Chichiray - It's the same issue, badges needed to be removed and re-awarded...some errant messages are a result of this.

Comment: @Nick: Ah ok, it's thus a side-effect of the mentioned bug? That might have been made more clear...

Comment: @Nick Craver: Then it is the same answer, but not the same question.