# Bug with Excavator Badge

Tags: bug, badges, edit-badges

I edited this post today [Fixed positioning in internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151577/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/2151609#2151609) on stack overflow. I was approved of the edit, so I waited a few minutes to get my [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator) badge because this answer was posted on Jan 28 '10 at 1:06, but it never came. I have read multiple articles on meta that there have been bugs with this badge, but they have been about winning it multiple times ([excavator badge: one-time only, or multiple times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102407/excavator-badge-one-time-only-or-multiple-times)), or earning it then losing it ([Where did my Excavator badge go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102425/where-did-my-excavator-badge-go)). Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need a little more patience than 12 minutes. If it's not there tomorrow evening, you can ask. The script for the Excavator badge doesn't run that often.

Comment: I have received all of my other badges within a few minutes. So I just thought I might have missed something

Comment: Well, badges are different. Some are awarded immediately, the script for others may run less often. I think the one for Legendary runs only twice a week.

Comment: What do you mean when you say run script

Comment: For most (or at least many) badges, there's a script that queries the database to see who shall get the badge this round. Some of the scripts run multiple times a day, some daily (tag badges, e.g.), some less than daily.

Comment: @CodyGuldner: There are scripts that run in certain intervals and determine *which* badges they're going to check for. Certain badges that are awarded more frequently have better chances of being checked, while badges that are awarded more infrequently (like Excavator) have lower chances of being checked. There's no "exact time" that it will eventually get checked, it's random. The last person who was awarded the badge got it ~50 minutes after their edit. So yes, there's a bit of a wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that @animuson and @Daniel Fischer were right. I just received the badge, 44 minutes after I answered the question. So it is a time based script that runs once every so often